# Display Posts of a Category in Alphabetical Order (Custom Post Type)

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, page-template

1. I have a **custom post type** called "link"
2. I have a **custom taxonomy** for this post type called "link-category"
3. I have a **template file** for this taxonomy, "taxonomy-link-category.php"
4. I need the template to display the posts of the selected link category in **alphabetical order**

**EDIT**: On the LINKS page of the website all of the category names for the custom post type **LINK** are displayed in a list. Once a visitor clicks a category name I need wordpress to list all the posts in that category, in alphabetical order. I have it working, with the code below (using template file: taxonomy-link-category.php), but the posts are displayed chronologically, and only 10 of them (the wordpress default).

I've tried things like this: [Displaying a custom post type alphabetically](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28653/displaying-a-custom-post-type-alphabetically) but of course it displays... **EDIT**: all of the LINK posts, not just the posts of the selected LINK category.

This is my current code in taxonomy-link-category.php, can I not just add `'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC'` somewhere/somehow?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
  <div id="content">                    
    <h1>Links</h1>
    <h2><?php echo get_queried_object()->name; ?></h2>
    <?php if (have_posts()) :   // start the loop ?>                    
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); // loop the posts ?>
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <?php the_content(); ?> 
        <?php endwhile;     // stop looping the posts ?>                                
        <?php else :        // what to do if there are no posts to show ?>
        <h3>No posts</h3>
    <?php endif;        // end the loop  ?>
  </div><!-- #content -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action to modify the query before it is run. Place this in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
function wpd_tax_alpha( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_tax('link-category') && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_tax_alpha' );
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you! And this is okay to do, no downfalls? no loop problems or extra database queries that might slow things down?

Comment: this is the preferred way to make any main query modifications, it runs before the database is queried, so no extra queries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  But I'm afraid I am misunderstanding your intent.

Have you tried:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'link', 
    'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'link-category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 'Birds', 'Cats', 'Dogs' )
    )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC' 
    );
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

That should produce an alphabetically sorted list where the array of terms is present in link-category taxonomy.

**EDIT original code was missing a comma after the terms array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Perhaps I should not have included the example categories of Birds, Cats, Dogs. The intent is for the website to have a links page, with many categories. Each category will have many posts. A visitor to the website will click a link category and view all the posts in that category. Categories will be added over time, so including an array would not be possible. All the links have a Title, URL, and Content to show. Is that more clear, or more confusing?

Comment: @codeview could you specify your problem a little more? I'd given the same answer as jdm2112 from what you're asking.

Comment: jdm2112, @alpipego - I've edited the original post with further explanation. Any additional help would be very much appreciated.